# Numeric matrix tiles in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Having a numeric matrix, how can tiles be extracted from it using Haskell?

---

Example:

```
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
getTile height width x y xs matrix_height matrix_width = ...
getTile 2 2 1 1 [1,2,3,4,5,
                 6,7,8,9,10] 2 5 = [2,3
                                    7,8]
```

Comment: What do you mean by tiles? How do you implement the matrix? Is it a list of lists? `every` has type `Int -> [a] -> [a]`, so I'm not seeing matrix-ey things so far.

Comment: @AndrásKovács currently I am using flat matrix. Tiles are e.g. region 2x2 starting at (1, 1)

Comment: I think that you should implement a 1-dimensional case (using `drop` and `take`), then it would be relatively easy to extend to n-dimensional case. Extract the rows dimension, from each row in a batch extract row spans and build tiles from them.

Comment: You should give an example (like for 2-d or 3-d matrix) of the input and desired output - that would answer a lot of questions.

Comment: So your 2D matrix is a 1D list with dimensions attached? Is this a principal requirement?

Comment: @9000 yes, but it is possible to convert between Matrix and Vector using Numeric.Matrix package as proposed by NovaDenizen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might instead want to use [Numeric.Matrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast-0.4.3/docs/Numeric-Matrix.html) from the bed-and-breakfast package.  It's a lot more efficient and has a good way of constructing a submatrix (fixed, select was inappropriate).

```
getTile height width x y m = matrix getElem (height,width) where
    getElem (i,j) = m `at` (i+x-1, j+y-1)
```

Numeric.Matrix uses 1-based indexing, so that might complicate matters a little.

Comment: That package is for... well, numeric matrices. Considering the asker uses the term 'tiles', I imagine he's really talking about grid like structure rather than a real matrix.

Comment: @Cubic asker has in mind arbitrary tiles on a numeric matrices. I believe it can be seen from the example

Comment: I also found out about `Data.Matrix`, it has `submatrix` function

Comment: I do not quite understand how Numeric.Matrix.select works using just two indices, would appreciate some example

Comment: `select` was the wrong function.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[submatrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.2.1/docs/Data-Matrix.html#v:submatrix)

```
import Data.Matrix

let flat_matrix=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let mat = Data.Matrix.fromList width height flat_matrix
let tile = submatrix start_row end_row start_column end_column mat
```